# Crear WebView con un tema obscuro

Tags: android, webview

Cree aplicación con un tema claro y obscuro, esta muestra en una `WebView` la descripción de un `'Evento'` para que se puedan ver imágenes, tablas y cosas así, pero en el tema obscuro, esta vista es de fondo blanco, lo cambia a negro con `css` básico para el texto y el fondo, podría poner lo demás para que el resto de los colores se vean bien. ¿Hay una mejor manera de hacer esto sin tener que poner el `css` de un tema obscuro?

style.css tiene los estilos para un tema obscuro, antes estaba cargándolo desde la web pero vi como se podiar cargar directamente desde el dispositivo

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.descricion_larga);
String htmlData = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" />" + evento.getDescripcionLarga();
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

funciona bien pero solo quiero saber si habría una mejor manera para que los cargue según el tema, por si tengo que cambiar los colores no tenga que cambiar el css

Comment: Muchas gracias por agregar lo que has intentado es importante para tener una idea de que es lo que deseas lograr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es correcto lo que realizas, definiendo un baseUrl "file:///android_asset/" que es donde se encontraría el archivo .css o imágenes que deseas cargar en el `WebView` que se mostraría en tu aplicación.

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

> quiero saber si habría una mejor manera para que los cargue según el
>   tema, por si tengo que cambiar los colores no tenga que cambiar el css

Al cambiar el tema en realidad no tienes comunicación con el `WebView` por lo tanto no puede cambiarse alguna propiedad, en este caso el color del fondo.

En caso de cambiar el color el .css este archivo no podrá ser modificado puesto que se encuentra en `/assets` y son recursos de solo lectura.

---

Como una opción para realizar lo que deseas es que cuando cambies el color de tu tema, definas en un "placeholder", en el cual reemplaces el color que deseas cambiar como fondo en el `WebView`, en este ejemplo  `[themeColor]` se sustituye por el color que deseas cambiar:

```
//String htmlData = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" />" + evento.getDescripcionLarga();
String htmlData = ""<style>body {background-color: [themeColor];}</style>""+ evento.getDescripcionLarga();
```

De esta forma dentro del `WebView` podrás realizar el cambio del fondo cuando cambies el tema en tu aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]